# constant number of functions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have the following conjecture:

Let $A, B$ be finite sets. Let $g : B \to A$. Then for each $f : A\to B$ with $g\circ f = id_A$ the number of functions $g' : B\to A$ having the property $g'\circ f = id_A$ is equal.

Is this conjecture true? Is there a more general version of this conjecture? If it is false, can my conjecture become a true conjecture by adding some hypotheses?

Comment: I don't understand your conjecture. Equal to what?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud: For each function $f : A\to B$ let $N(f)$ be the number of functions $g:B\to A$ with $g'\circ f = id_A$. I conjecture that for all $f_1:A\to B$ and $f_2:A\to B$, $N(f_1) = N(f_2)$. Is it now understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and you can explicitly count the number of such $g'$ just in terms of the sizes of $A$ and $B$.  Suppose $A$ has $n$ elements and $B$ has $m$ elements.  Since at least one such $g'$ exists (namely $g$), $f$ is injective.  In order to have $g'\circ f=id_A$, you just need that $g'(f(a))=a$ for all $a\in A$.  This uniquely determines $g'$ on the image $f(A)\subseteq B$, and $g'$ can take any values at all on the rest of $B$.  So such $g'$ are just in bijection with functions $B\setminus f(A)\to A$.  There are $n^{m-n}$ such functions, since $|A|=n$ and $|B\setminus f(A)|=m-n$.

Comment: Is there a more general version of my conjecture that is also true?

Comment: What sort of more general version do you want?  What do you want to do with this statement, exactly?

Comment: @EricWofsey: Maybe the following generalization. We drop the assumption of $A, B$ being finite and conjecture that for each two functions $f_1, f_2 : A\to B$ with $gf = id$ there is a bijection between $N(f_1)$ and $N(f_2)$, where $N(f)$ denotes the set of all $g'$ with $g'f = id$. Is this true too?