# constant number of functions in the infinite

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Conjecture: Let $A, B$ be two possibly infinite sets. Let $g:B\to A$. Then for any two functions $f_1,f_2:A→B$ with $gf_i=id$ there is a bijection between $N(f_1)$ and $N(f_2)$, where $N(f)$ denotes, for a given $f:A\to B$, the set of all $g′$ with $g′f=id$.

Is this conjecture true?

[This thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2311248/constant-number-of-functions) asks the same question for finite sets, and the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ran}{\mathop{\text{ran}}}$
Yes, there is a bijection between these two sets. Note first that if $b\in B$ is in $\ran(f_1)\cap\ran(f_2)$ and $g(b)=a$, then since $g\circ f_1=g\circ f_2=\text{id}$, we have $f_1(a)=f_2(a)=b$. So, if $h\in N(f_1)$, it does the "right" job also for $f_2$ on the common range.

Note also that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are injective. Thus, there is an obvious involution on $\ran(f_1)\triangle\ran(f_2)$, switching $\ran(f_1)\setminus\ran(f_2)$ with $\ran(f_2)\setminus\ran(f_1)$. (Just take the preimage under one function and map it forward via the other.) Let $s$ be the extension of this function to all of $B$ via the identity function.

Then, if $h\in N(f_1)$, letting $h'=h\circ s$ we have $h'\in N(f_2)$. That is:
$$h'(x)=\begin{cases}h(x) &\text{if }x\in \ran(f_1)\cap\ran(f_2),\\
h(f_1(f_2^{-1}(x))) &\text{if }x\in\ran(f_2)\setminus\ran(f_1),\\
h(f_2(f_1^{-1}(x)))&\text{if }x\in\ran(f_1)\setminus\ran(f_2),\\
h(x)&\text{if }x\not\in\ran(f_1)\cup\ran(f_2). \end{cases} $$

Obviously, for $h'$ as above we also have $h'\circ s=h$. It is then easy to see that $s$ induces a bijection between $N(f_1)$ and $N(f_2)$. I'll leave to details to you.